# How do I save a BGRA image to iphone and then take it to a laptop for post-processing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to use iphone's camera to take a raw image data and then use matlab or opencv in the laptop to post-process it. So I need take this raw image data from the iphone to the laptop.

Currently, I use AVFoudnation to get 32BGRA image (it is the raw image data, right?). And I save it as a file, but I cannot take it from the iphone. (Is there any solutions without jailbreak?)

Following are some relevant codes:

```
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {                                   
                // get the raw image data
                let cameraFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

                CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame!, 0)

                let rawImage = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame!)
                let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame!)
                let rawImageData = NSData.init(bytes: rawImage, length: bytesPerRow*CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame!))

                // process the rawImageData, we now save it
                var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true);
                let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
                let fileName = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/rawImageData")                    

                do {
                    try rawImageData.writeToFile(fileName, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingFileProtectionComplete)
                } catch {

                }
                print("Raw image data write successfully.")
                print("Path of raw image data: ", fileName)                   
                CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame!, 0)               
            }
        })
    }
```

Should I need save the BGRA data to the photo album and then take it out, if so, how can I do it (use UIImage?)

Thanks.

An update:

I transform BGRA image to UIImage and use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to save it to the photo album, then I use airdrop to take the image file to may mac. However, I found the image is JPEG format. What's wrong?
Following are the codes:

```
            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {                   
                let rawImage:UIImage = self.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                self.capturedImage.image = rawImage
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(rawImage, nil, nil, nil)                    
                print("Raw Image write to photo album successfully")  
            }

// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer : CMSampleBufferRef) -> UIImage
{
// Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
let  imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
// Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, 0);


// Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!);

// Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!);
// Get the pixel buffer width and height
let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer!);
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!);

// Create a device-dependent RGB color space
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

// Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue
bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);
// Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
let quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
// Unlock the pixel buffer
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!,0);

// Create an image object from the Quartz image
let image = UIImage.init(CGImage: quartzImage!);

return (image);
}
```

Comment: What format do you want to use it in for MATLAB? Can't MATLAB import any kind of image?

Comment: Matlab cannot import BGRA image, can I save the raw data as bmp in iphone and take it out to the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution: convert the BGRA to UIImage, and to PNG, then save it to the photo album. Since PNG is a lossless compression image format, it means I get the bmp image as well.

```
                let rawImage:UIImage = self.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)                    
                let img = UIImagePNGRepresentation(rawImage)
                let pngImg = UIImage.init(data: img!)                                       
                self.capturedImage.image = pngImg
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pngImg!, nil, nil, nil)                   
                print("PNG Image write to photo album successfully")
```